# Javascript Sum currency

Tags: javascript

I want to sum up a simple currency
Here are my codes

```
function calculateText2(){

var op11=document.getElementById('home_mortgage');
var op22=document.getElementById('credit_card');
var op33=document.getElementById('car_loan');
var op44=document.getElementById('personal_loan');
var op55=document.getElementById('tax_debt');
var op66=document.getElementById('other_investment');
var op77=document.getElementById('other2');
var op88=document.getElementById('other3');

var result1=document.getElementById('total2');

if(op11.value=="" || op11.value!=parseFloat(op11.value)) op11.value=0;

if(op22.value=="" || op22.value!=parseFloat(op22.value)) op22.value=0;
if(op33.value=="" || op33.value!=parseFloat(op33.value)) op33.value=0;
if(op44.value=="" || op44.value!=parseFloat(op44.value)) op44.value=0;
if(op55.value=="" || op55.value!=parseFloat(op55.value)) op55.value=0;
if(op66.value=="" || op66.value!=parseFloat(op66.value)) op66.value=0;
if(op77.value=="" || op77.value!=parseFloat(op77.value)) op77.value=0;
if(op88.value=="" || op88.value!=parseFloat(op88.value)) op88.value=0;

result1.value=0;

result.value=parseInt(result.value);

result.value=parseInt(result.value)+parseInt(op1.value)+parseInt(op2.value)+parseInt(op3.value)+parseInt(op4.value)+parseInt(op5.value)+parseInt(op6.value)+parseInt(op7.value)+parseInt(op8.value);}
```

The problem is, it sums up the numbers, but not decimals. 
Thanks.

Comment: wat does parseCurrency() look like...?

Comment: Where is `parseCurrency()` ?

Comment: You really need to look into arrays. You shouldn't be typing out huge numbers of variables whose names only differ by a trailing number.

Comment: Sorry its not really parse currency. editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you are parsing to integer not float (you are ignoring the decimal part of your string) try change the `parseInt` to `parseFloat`

```
result.value=parseFloat(result.value);

result.value=parseFloat(result.value)+parseFloat(op1.value)+parseFloat(op2.value)+parseFloat(op3.value)+parseFloat(op4.value)+parseFloat(op5.value)+parseFloat(op6.value)+parseFloat(op7.value)+parseFloat(op8.value);
```